# Pass a UIElement class parameter to an assembly class?

Tags: c#, .net

I have an assembly on one end that needs to take a wpf UIElement class as a parameter. Should be easy enough, but in the assembly, there is no UIElement class even when using System.Windows. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [`UIElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is in "PresentationCore.dll", do you have a reference to that in your assembly's project?

Comment: I had System.Windows added, but I didn't know that you needed presentation core also. It works wonderfully now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though `UIElement` is in the `System.Windows` namespace, the actual class is in the "PresentationCore.dll" assembly.  In order to access that class you will need to add a reference to that dll.

If you run in to problems like this in the future, look the class up on MSDN. Near the top it will list both the Namespace, and the Assembly that the class resides in.

[image]